# Is it possible to completely duplicate the state of a user profile?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, user-profiles

I have spent hours adjusting the local user profile on my machine... and "OH BOY" is it far off from a typical clean install of Win 10 Home. Started with a clean install, proceeded with a change of settings, continued with the removal of Microsoft recommended bloatware, and neared the end with extensive yet far from complete registry edits. I would say that the "editing" process is satisfactory. The only thing I would need at this point is a way to literally "completely duplicate" the "state" of "everything".

So in a nutshell, I need help to find a way to take my local user profile and create a completely indistinguishable secondary local profile. Only difference would be that I would rename the new account to guest or something.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You can make symbolic links of yours appdata in another partition. But not the whole user folder.

Comment: Make a symbolic link of the **NTUSER.DAT** too. If you would like to clone the profile without interfering with the first profile, try copying the files mentioned by me and @Biswapriyo.